# Find the values of $r?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider  the  matrix   $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1  & r \end{bmatrix}$ .For   which   values  of  $r$  is  the  matrix  $A$  diagonalizable  over $\mathbb{R}$

**My attempt** :$A - xI= \begin{bmatrix} 1-x & -1 \\ 1  & r-x \end{bmatrix}=(1-x)(r-x)+1=0$

$$\implies  x^2 - x(r+1) + (1+r)=0$$

$b^2-4ac= (r+1)^2-4(r+1)\ge 0$  for  real roots

That means  $(r+1)^2\ge 4(r+1)\implies 4(r+1) >0 \implies r>-1$

Therefore  if  $r >- 1$  then  the  matrix  $A$  is diagonalizable  over $\mathbb{R}$

What do you think, am I right?

Comment: $(r+1)^2\ge 4(r+1)\Rightarrow 4(r+1)>0$ is false.

Comment: okay @Manifoldski . My understanding is that a $(r+1)^2$  is  always  positive. This  implies  $4(r+1) >0$. Thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding

Comment: okay @SassatelliGiulio that means $ r > 3$ is the right   answer.Am i right ?

Comment: There is a mechanical procedure to solve the inequation $x^2+bx+c\ge 0$, I suggest you do that.

Comment: The inequality holds if $r \notin (-1, 3)$.

Comment: We have that

$$(r+1)^2\ge 4(r+1) \iff (r+1)^2- 4(r+1)\ge 0 \iff (r+1)(r-3)\ge 0$$

that is $r\le -1 \lor r\ge 3$.

Comment: Make sure to check the repeated root cases for diagonalizability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a *necessary* condition for diagonalizability is that the characteristic polynomial of
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & r \end{pmatrix} $$
splits as a product of linear factors over the ground field $k$. This is because characteristic polynomials are invariant under conjugation. I therefore compute:
$$ \chi(x) = x^{2} + (-1-r)x + (r+1). $$
The discriminant of $\chi$ is $(r - 1)(r + 3)$. In the case $k = \mathbf{R}$, the discriminant completely determines the splitting behavior of $\chi$. Indeed, the proposition that $\chi$ splits over $\mathbf{R}$ translates in the language of discriminants to the inequality
$$ (r + 1)(r - 3) \geq 0. $$
This inequality is in turn equivalent to the proposition that $r \leq -1$ or $r \geq 3$.

(As an aside, we can [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3gCO.gif) the zero locus of $x^{2} + (-1-r)x + (r+1)$ in the $(r,x)$-plane to make graphic the eigenvalues of $A$ as a function in $r$. Note that the plot confirms the algebra.)

We are not yet done, for this inequality does not suffice for diagonalizability. Consider for instance the case $r = -1$, i.e., the matrix
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}. $$
By inspecting the characteristic polynomial $\chi$, we see that the only eigenvalue is $0$. If the matrix in question were diagonalizable, it would have to be of the form
$$ B^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}B $$
for some $B \in \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbf{R})$. However, there is only one such matrix, and it is not $A$. The same argument mutatis mutandis demonstrates that $A$ fails to be diagonalizable when $r = 3$.

We are now near completion. Once more, recall the discriminant completely determines the splitting behavior of $\chi$. In particular, if the discriminant is positive, $\chi$ has two distinct roots. This implies $A$ is diagonalizable. In sum, $A$ is diagonalizable precisely when $r < -1$ or $r > 3$.